# AWS ElasticBeanstalk using Babel to build distribution before application launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, babeljs

Currently I have a AWS EB stack setup using the default 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.3 running Node.js AMI.

Our codebase is written in ES6 and we use Babel to transpile the code into ES5. Our current deployment process is running babel locally to build the `/dist` directory and commiting the dist into our git repository and using `eb deploy` to deploy the application to EB.

I would like to be able to remove the step of building the distribution locally and perform this operation on the EB server.

I have tried using `.ebextensions` with a `command` to execute `npm run build` which yields an error `Return code: 127 Output: /bin/sh: npm: command not found.`. I have also tried using `files` to insert the file into the `appdeploy/pre` which yields the same error. And I have tried using `container_commands` which also yields an error stating that `npm` is not available.

Which of the available deployment hooks that AWS EB provides would be the correct place to use `npm run build`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm hooks.
For example:
Here I have a `npm start` command that fires my server but before it I have a `babel . -d ./dist` to compile the files on the dist directory. So I have a task called `prestart` ( using the npm hook pre naming convention ) that does that.